# Function as argument to another function JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, callback, arguments

I am trying to pass a function as an argument to another function.

```
//Scroll To + Remove Class if exists


$(document).on( "click", "a[href^=\\#]", function () {

    $( "html, body" ).animate({

      scrollTop:  $('section[data-attr-target="'+this.hash.slice(1)+'"]').offset().top }, 300 ); 

    return false;

}, fun());

function fun() {

  if(("menu").hasClass("active")) {

     $("menu").removeClass("active");

  }
}
```

[JS Bin full example](https://jsbin.com/saqozipise/edit?html,css,js,output)

What I expect of my function:

1. Click event
2. Scroll to a section
3. fun() starts and checks up whether $("menu") has a class of "active", if so it removes it.

**fun()** among function arguments breaks behavior (without it function works for scroll to an element), but I need **fun()** to check the class of $("menu") element.

Please, explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: jQuery's `on()` doesn't take two callbacks, you probably wanted to call that function **before** the `return false; },` part, right after the animate part, this is what you really wanted to do -> **https://jsfiddle.net/qxkmygzb/**

Comment: If I put my fun() function before "return false" it doesn't check the class, it isn't executed as I can understand

Comment: FYI: you don't have to check anything to remove the class, just do as in the fiddle I posted above

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can just write the whole function inside the code of my "main" function. But I'd like to know how to add my "checking" function as an argument to the existing construction. If it's possible at all, of course.

Comment: ***And again***, see the fiddle above, where the callback for the animation is used to remove the class. You can't add your function as a second callback to the click function, the closest you'll get is as the callback for the animation, like this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/qxkmygzb/1/**

Comment: But it ruins the order I wrote in description: Click - Scroll - Remove class. It just removes class on click at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `complete function` that is called once the animation on an element is complete.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/tg5op333/29/

```
$(document).on( "click", "a[href^=\\#]", function () {
    $( "html, body" ).animate({
      scrollTop:  $('section[data-attr-target="'+this.hash.slice(1)+'"]').offset().top},
      {duration: 300,
      specialEasing: {
      width: "linear",
      height: "easeOutBounce"
      },
      complete: function() {
            fun();
       }
   });
});
```